# Is it legit to change the CKRecordID of a CKRecord in Cloudkit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have an object Person and an object Address. I want to store these objects to Cloudkit. It is possible that multiple persons have the same address, so there is a 1:m relationship. I store a ckreference on the person object. Now I wonder, if I should give the address a random recordid/recordname provided from cloudkit ore one consisting of the addressdetails, eg. street, city ...

The later solution would mean, I must change the address recordid everytime I'll change details.

Does that have any sideeffects on the person's address ckreference? Which solution is better more usable?

Comment: What would be the benefit of making your own record id that consists of other data in the record? A record id is never supposed to change once set.

Comment: In my head, the benefit would be not to have another field to save the recordName of the object. I didn't see that information in the documentation, that a recordid is never supposed to change once set. But that would answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

In CloudKit references are declared using the `CKReference` class. Don't reinvent the wheel ;-)

A CKRecord identifier never changes.

You have to take care about the kind of [referenceAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckreferenceaction) selected at `CKReference` creation time. Setting `.deleteSelf` only allow a **limited** records references to that record, in the other hand, a `.none` reference action allows you an unlimimted number of references to that CKRecord.

The best choice is CKReference.